# Trying to use Conditional Formatting in excel to highlight a cell if my formula is false

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

So recently I have created a ton of formulas to automate some data so manual checking doesn't need to be done. I have all my formulas created, and all of them contain IF statements that either contain "True", if all the conditions are met in the formula, or if it is false, it contains the exact problem in terms of text.

Ex. ("First digit is wrong", "Digits 2-7 are wrong", etc).

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to make things a little more clear for people that use the system in the future, but I'm kind of confused on how conditional formatting works when you use your own formula.

I'm trying to check each column (each column contains a different formula), for anything that isn't "True", so I don't need to make conditions for all the different strings I have for when something is wrong. Not really sure how to start so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right you have a bunch of cells that contain the text "True" or lots of other text ("First digit is wrong", "Digits 2-7 are wrong", etc).  ?

like this:

```
    A                       B                           C
1   True                    Digits 2-7 are wrong        You are wrong
2   bunchofstuff            Digits 2-7 are wrong        bad
3   bunchofstuff            True                        bunchofstuff
4   First digit is wrong    True                        True
```

IF so :
select cells A1:C4, and go to **conditional formatting** --> Highlight cell rules --> more rules --> format only cells that contain

in the drop downs choose: **cell value** & **not equal to**. In the box on the right type (exactly, including quotes): **="True"**

select your **format** (red fill) and click **ok**.

**ALTERNATIVELY**

you may also just type your conditional formula :

select cells A1:C4,  then go to :

conditional formatting --> new formula --> use a formula to determine... -->

put **=IF(A1="True",FALSE,TRUE)** in the box,

choose your format(red fill). click ok

Comment: Yea, you got it perfectly. Thanks!